# How to type the black hole register command "_d in vim?

Tags: vim

This must be a really dumb question, but I could not find the answer after spending hours googling it.

I learned from some tutorial that "_d deletes the content into black hole register. But how exactly is the "_d command typed in vim?

In the following example, if I want to delete the first word "example" into black hole register, what are the exact key strokes I need to make? And the same question for deleting the first line into black whole register?

```
example line 1
example line 2
```

Comment: Exactly those. Just make sure you hit `ESC` until you're in Normal mode first.

Comment: Just do the key strokes that normally make these characters appear on the screen. On a US English keyboard, Shift-`'`, followed by Shift-`-`, followed by `d`.

Comment: For a bit of insight - `"` (quote) says "use a register for the next yank/delete/paste operation". `_` (underscore) is the name of the void register (black hole, where everything disappears without trace). Then `d` is your normal "delete" command. If you manage to type the text `"_dd` (delete and forget a line) into the insert mode and see it in your text, just press the exact same keys in normal mode to execute it. You could even copy-paste it from here if you are using terminal Vim (you can't with GUI Vim, as it will detect the paste and automatically insert).

Answer (score 2):

You also need a motion for the command, so that it knows, what exactly to delete. That can either be a visual selection or a motion command. Starting in normal mode:

- To delete the first word (cursor at start of "example"):

  ```
  "_dw
  ```
- Select "example", then delete current selection:

  ```
  vw"_d
  ```
- Deleting the whole line:

  ```
  "_dd
  ```

You get the idea.